# What criteria are required for fields to be equated?

Tags: c#, java, sql, sql-server, database

I'm building a query builder module in C# and Java, where users can join tables based on a specified join expression, for example `[Table1].[ID] = [Table2].[ID]`.

Users can modify the join expression, and can choose to equate any field from `Table1` with any field in `Table2`.

I thought of checking to see whether the column data types and lengths are the same, however a `varchar(10)` column can be joined with an `nchar(10)` column for example. As long as the lengths are the same, these different data types can be selected.

Thus, what conditions should I specify in my checks to see that the user's selected join expression is valid? I cannot rely on PK/FK constraints alone.

The criteria could be applied to C# or Java - does not matter, as once I have a general answer I can convert my solution to fit both.

Comment: How are you accessing the database? Can you even tell what type the fields themselves are from your code?

Comment: @Bobson - Yes it's very easy to accomplish that. A number of libraries exist, as well as SQL statements carried out to sys.INFORMATION_SCHEMA. This is not what I'm asking.

Comment: You can check the size of the column  using `size(columnName)`. And if  the size returns same for the column of both table then you allow the joining..else flash an error message.

Comment: @VishalK - That's one scenario however. You can also join fields if for example one is `varchar` and the other is `nchar`. How could I check this scenario? As by only allowing equal datatypes to be joined, it would not work for this case, no?

Comment: I can check the type of column yes, but what if one is an `nchar` and the other is `varchar`? Wont those not be equal?

Comment: OK..First you can check the type of column using `DESC` query for both table.. And after the datatype is matched .. you can proceed to find out the length of both column value using `LENGTH` function.. If both test are passed then allow the the `joining` else flash error message...Now regarding `nchar` and `varchar` You can put this in exception situation..

Comment: Yes, but my point is that SQL Server allows you to join certain data types even if they are not equal. Like `nchar` and `varchar`. Or are these considered to be equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to simply have hardcoded sets, and then check whether both fields are in the same set, and only *then* compare the length.

```
var TypeSets = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> {
                   { "string", new[] { "varchar", "nchar", "text" } },
                   { "integer", new[] { "int", "smallint" } },
               };
```

Then:

```
if (TypeSets.Any(x => x.Value.Contains(fieldType1) && x.Value.Contains(fieldType2)))
{
   // Check length of each field
}
else 
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So hardcoding it is the way to go? My only issue with that is that there is an unreal amount of data types so it would take quite a while to compile such a list.

Comment: @DotNET - I don't know that it's the *best* way, but it's probably the safest.  The alternative would be to try and guess based on what's convertible, and that could lead to problems down the road.

Answer (score 2):

Books Online will give you the datatypes and which can be implicityl converted, which must be explicitly converted and which cannot convert. Search for CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)  and scroll down.

You should be able to build some sort of rules engine now that you knw the rules.